# point in time prediction for time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have 2 datasets. One is a time series data of monthly temperature at first date of the month, something similar to the one below.

| month_start | temperature_celsius |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.2021 | 2.3 |
| 1.2.2021 | 0.5 |
| 1.3.2021 | 8.6 |
| 1.4.2021 | 11.5 |
| 1.5.2021 | 23.8 |
| -------- | -------- |

and so on.

I have another data-set (feature set) with multiple features and date of observation. Basically I want to add the temperature data closest (pandas merge_asof with backward direction) to the observation date. This part is easy to implement. However, I am also doing a one-step-ahead forecasting of the temperature time series data to predict for future months.

Now, suppose I have an observation with date as 10.8.2021. I would like to merge based on the predicted temperature on 1.8.2021. This would have been simple for fixed dates, but each observation have different dates and I would like to take all the prior data for each one and predict the temp at next closest date.

Is there any prior methods to dynamically estimate the next step forecast based on the cutoff date for each observation?

Comment: If your temperature dataframe always has month_start, and you always want backward direction. Can't you just remove the days from the datestamp to merge?

Comment: Do you want to predict based on the df with month starts or the other way around?

Comment: Also, I don't completely understand this "take all the prior data" , that would multiply your rows in the original df. It would be probably better to use some aggregation from prior data, such as mean.

Comment: @BorutFlis I want to predict the temperature for future months, and then use the forecasts on the feature set (which I then use to train a linear model).

Comment: @BorutFlis Yes, it will have duplicated entries since I am trying to build a time hazard model that will include the changes over time. For the same unique identifier, the parameters can change over time. I am trying to include this in my model.